# Implementing RTSP server in Java to stream video on VLC Media Player

Tags: java, streaming, vlc, rtsp, rtp

I am implementing an RTSP streaming server having the VLC media player as a client. After starting the server when I try to stream the videos on VLC, it sends a SETUP request to the server. I'm trying to send the response following the RTSP and SDP protocol.

my `sendresponse()` is implemented as follows:

```
private void sendResponse() {
        try {
                    System.out.println("Sending response to the server for the SETUP request");
                    RTSPBufferedWriter.write("RTSP/1.0 200 OK" + CRLF);
                    System.out.println("RTSP/1.0 200 OK" + CRLF);
                    RTSPBufferedWriter.write("CSeq: " + RTSPSeqNb + CRLF);
                    System.out.println("CSeq: "+RTSPSeqNb + CRLF);
                    RTSPBufferedWriter.write("Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port="+RTSP_dest_port+"-"+(RTSP_dest_port+1)+";server_port=8080-8081"+ CRLF);
                    RTSPBufferedWriter.write("Session: " + RTSPid + CRLF);
                    System.out.println("Session: "+  RTSPid + CRLF);
                    RTSPBufferedWriter.flush();//
                    System.out.println("RTSP Server - Sent response to Client using the send response method.");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Exception caught while sending response to SETUP request: " + ex);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
    }
```

and my RTSP BufferedWritter was initiated as follows:

```
       RTSPBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(server.RTSPsocket.getOutputStream()));
```

The problem I'm facing here is can't send the response to vlc player for the setup request and the player is like buffering. The request sent to the server from vlc is as follows:

```
SETUP rtsp://localhost:8080 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 0
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=9194-9195
```

I'm facing difficulties to successfully sent the response to VLC and to start streaming and wandering aboout the right way to send response to vlc, and also about how to know that vlc is received the respose. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

**Update** here's the log of vlc media player:

```
-- logger module started --
main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
main: playlist is empty
live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://127.0.0.1:8080
satip error: read error: No error
satip error: Failed to setup RTSP session
main error: connection failed: Connection refused by peer
access_realrtsp error: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:8080
-- logger module stopped --
```

Comment: Please share the logs too . check the port no where the messages are send and where your response is going. check if is over UDP or TCP.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, here the vlc log: ` -- logger module started --
main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
main: playlist is empty
live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://127.0.0.1:8080
satip error: read error: No error
satip error: Failed to setup RTSP session
main error: connection failed: Connection refused by peer
access_realrtsp error: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:8080
-- logger module stopped -- `

Comment: Please add the server side logs (add the logs in your question) and check the pcap (wireshark) for the port details and the message flow. Don't run the server and the client on the same machine.

Comment: I'm actually following the instructions from here and trying to extend it for vlc, The provided code is working fine for the java client but not for vlc.code is here >> ` https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/lab5-kurose-ross.html `  the main problem I'm facing here is I can't get any response from vlc after sending response to any of the vlc request.

Comment: Based on your vlc logs : "live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://127.0.0.1:8080 " your socket connection itself is not successful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'm sharing my ` Server.java ` file with you. Here is it: https://gist.github.com/monir-code/886158308998c03fd107ee4b1782478d could you manage some time to see the file? specially from line 145 where the implementations for tcp is written? I will be greatful if you suggest something to make the code compatiable with vlc as a client and to successfully establish the tcp connection. thanks

Comment: Request you to do the experiments and let me know the results .. I can guide you to the solution.